# How to print characters in character array without duplicate?

Tags: java

I was asked to write a program to print values in a character array. This array contains duplicated values, but output should not contain duplicated characters.**Do not use Set**. This is what I have created. Let me know if there is any other and efficient way to do the same.

```
public class RemoveDuplication {
  public static void main (String[] args){
    char[] a= new char[]{'a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c'};
    String s=Character.toString(a[0]);

    for (int i=1; i<a.length; i++) {
      if ((s.indexOf(a[i])) == -1) {
        s = s + Character.toString(a[i]);
      } else {
      }
    }
    // if you want character array as result 
    char[] result = s.toCharArray();
    System.out.println(result);
  }
}
```

Comment: `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result));`

Comment: Hi Elliott, Thanks for suggestion.
 Please note that we have overloaded 'println' method which accepts char array as argument and prints list of values in char array.

Answer (score 1):

You are over-doing.

Just go for:

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder().append(a[0]);
```

and then `append()` to that builder object; and in the end; call `builder.toString()`. Instead of all the funny things you do with that `s` string variable.

Your code that is going  from and back between String and Character and using + for string appending is as said; very much over-complicating things.

Comment: Yes ! Thanks for your suggestion buddy (y)

Comment: You are very welcome ... and funny thing: I assumed you wouldn't be allowed to use a set, that is why i didn't mention that part; as you already got that part to find the duplicates correctly ;-)

Comment: hi, how to know if the the given character already present in the string builder object.

if ((s.indexOf(a[i])) == -1)  this line of code is not valid if s is StringBuilder.

Comment: You could always do: builder.toString().indexOf(), too

Answer (score 1):

If you use a Set object, it will do that for you.

```
Set<Character> s = new HashSet<>();
s.add('c');
s.add('c');
//c was only added once
```

then iterate like this:

```
for(Character c: s)
{
    System.out.println(c);
}
```

Comment: Yeahh ! its great solution but i was not allowed to use Set :(

Answer (score 0):

Stream the characters, filter to only distinct code points, then collect the code points in a `StringBuilder` and finally print it out:

```
System.out.println(
    str.chars().distinct().boxed()
        .collect(Collector.of(StringBuilder::new,
                    StringBuilder::appendCodePoint,
                    StringBuilder::append)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Each time I hear **unique elements**, **Sets** comes to my mind. So here is the easiest implementation using `sets`:

```
char[] a= new char[]{'a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c'};

Set<Character> set = new HashSet<Character>(); //declare Set of Character type
for(char c : a)
        set.add(c);           //Add chars in 'a' to the set 

System.out.println(set);
```

> OUTPUT : [a, b, c]

Comment: Oh, seems the question was edited to say **do not use sets** when I was typing out the answer. Since its already posted, I think its fine if it remains.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do to speedup this is something like, check if the character C is in the outputted characters array A (not the print) using binary search. Print the character C if it's not in the list and then insert (sorted) the character C to A (to be able to use binary search).